# Filtering on unique values doesn't work properly

Tags: r, dplyr

## The Problem

I have 2 dataframes : `cube` and `hub` with variables called `knb_nd` and `nd`

```
|      cube$knb_nd    |
|---------------------|
|          01         |
|          02         |
|          05         |
|          05         |
|          NA         |
|          07         |
```

```
|      hub$nd         |
|---------------------|
|          01         |
|          02         |
|          02         |
|          01         |
|          NA         |
```

I want to have a subset of `cube` based on the `knb_nd` which are not present in `hub`

```
|      restult$nd     |
|---------------------|
|          05         |
|          07         |
```

## What I tried

I tried to filter with base R using the `unique()` function on the dataframe, but when I search for a ND it still shows up in both dataframes. Same issue with the `dplyr` version.

```
# base R version
cube[!c(unique(cube$knb_nd) %in% unique(hub$nd)),]

# dplyr version
cube %>% 
  filter(!c(knb_nd %in% unique(hub$nd)))
```

I know there is probably a easy and obvious way to find it, but I can't seem to have it on my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue in the `base R`

```
cube[!c(unique(cube$knb_nd) %in% unique(hub$nd)),]
```

The `unique(cube$knb_nb)` could return `length` shorter than the original `length` of the column, thus the logical vector derived will be also be of shorter length creating an incorrect subset.  Instead it would be

```
cube[!cube$knb_nd %in% unique(hub$nd),]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)

result <- unique(anti_join(cube, hub, by = c("knb_nd" = "nd"))) %>% 
  rename(nd = knb_nd)
```

```
  nd
1  5
3  7
```

Comment: With this method some nd are still in both dataframes. I'm really confused why

Comment: try this : `result <- unique(anti_join(cube %>% 
                             type.convert(as.is = TRUE), 
                           hub %>% 
                             type.convert(as.is = TRUE), by = c("knb_nd" = "nd"))) %>% 
  rename(nd = knb_nd)`